# Highcharts - rangeSelector 3M is not responding after selecting 7Y

Tags: highcharts

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. Click on 3M (working fine)
2. Click on 7Y(working fine)
3. Click on 3M(**not working**)

**Code :**

```
buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3M',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6M',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'ytd',
                text: 'YTD'
            }, 
            {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1Y',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            },
             {
                type: 'year',
                count: 7,
                text: '7Y',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            }

            ]
```

**Demo :**
http://jsfiddle.net/nhb1812d/2/

Comment: Why you use month paratemr in units? Remove dataGrouping, generally and then all will work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/rLw3hmL5/

Comment: But the requirement is showing data month wise. what to do now